# Time to first byte is massive on Joomla site

Tags: performance, joomla

Time to first byte on www.netdyrlaege.dk is really big. 
This is unfortunately an issue that is beyond my skills. 
I have optimized everything as well as possible and now I get on only one F webpagetest.org 
The TimeToFirstByte is crazy large!

I'm on a virtual private server, bought a big one, it is not a server issue.
No, it is something within Joomla. I've been able to reduce loading times from up to 12 seconds to something like from 3-5 seconds. That is still not okay.

I tried Joomla debug and here are these results. AfterDispatch is from 0.7 to 1.8 seconds depending on the browser! What is this and why?
How do I fix this?

Profile information

```
Application 0.001 seconds (+0.001); 1.34 MB (+1.336) - afterLoad<br>
Application 0.075 seconds (+0.075); 10.53 MB (+9.196) - afterInitialise<br>
Application 0.162 seconds (+0.087); 23.64 MB (+13.113) - afterRoute<br>
Application 0.747 seconds (+0.585); 34.98 MB (+11.336) - afterDispatch<br>
Application 0.808 seconds (+0.061); 37.29 MB (+2.309) - beforeRenderModule <br>mod_customerswhobought (Customers Who Bought...)<br>
Application 0.815 seconds (+0.007); 37.35 MB (+0.062) - afterRenderModule mod_customerswhobought (Customers Who Bought...)
Application 0.819 seconds (+0.004); 37.36 MB (+0.013) - beforeRenderModule mod_vm_prod_cat_full (Butik menu all left)
Application 1.065 seconds (+0.247); 37.51 MB (+0.141) - afterRenderModule mod_vm_prod_cat_full (Butik menu all left)
Application 1.065 seconds (+0.000); 37.51 MB (+0.007) - beforeRenderModule mod_vm_s5_column_cart_AJAX (Kurv med billeder)<br>
Application 1.426 seconds (+0.360); 47.91 MB (+10.393) - afterRenderModule mod_vm_s5_column_cart_AJAX (Kurv med billeder)<br>
Application 1.427 seconds (+0.001); 47.90 MB (-0.010) - beforeRenderModule mod_breadcrumbs (breadcrumbs)<br>
Application 1.432 seconds (+0.005); 47.94 MB (+0.041) - afterRenderModule mod_breadcrumbs (breadcrumbs)<br>
Application 1.433 seconds (+0.002); 47.93 MB (-0.004) - beforeRenderModule mod_vm_prod_cat_full (Butik menu all)<br>
Application 1.646 seconds (+0.213); 47.98 MB (+0.050) - afterRenderModule mod_vm_prod_cat_full (Butik menu all)<br>
Application 1.647 seconds (+0.001); 47.99 MB (+0.011) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu (Top Menu)<br>
Application 1.653 seconds (+0.006); 48.15 MB (+0.154) - afterRenderModule mod_menu (Top Menu)<br>
Application 1.654 seconds (+0.000); 48.06 MB (-0.085) - beforeRenderModule mod_virtuemart_mini_cart (mini kurv)<br>Application 1.658 seconds (+0.004); 48.08 MB (+0.021) - afterRenderModule mod_virtuemart_mini_cart (mini kurv)<br>
Application 3.524 seconds (+1.866); 49.01 MB (+0.927) - afterRender<br>
```

On

Answer (score 1):

first of all disable debug on your site: end-users will question the stability of the site and attackers gain plenty of info.

In order to achieve optimization you should:

- perform all configuration tasks that will allow you to gain speed (mainly, setup and use cache properly!)
- see the modules in the debug list, and ensure they use cache; load the page twice and see if at least the second time it loads under one sec.

(Now you should be down to 1 second rendering time)

Then, the tough part begins:

- examine your site's debug, and identify the plugins slowing down the site. The modules are already listed;
- starting from the slowest, ponder if you can live without it, or get your hands on the code and fix it;

(Now you should be down to 100 - 300 ms)

- configure the server to perform optimally
- evaluate external cache solutions

(Now you should be below 50ms)

The more you optimize, the harder it will be to obtain substantial results. I bet I could get you down to 200ms in less than 3 hours, but then it would take days to get to 20ms.

And don't forget this is just rendering time, you also might want to optimize your page, you're using many libraries, making many calls that can be saved, graphics could be combined... and that's affecting the speed too.

Your site's homepage currently runs 900 queries in the homepage. This is way more than you need, there must be some pretty poorly optimized extensions there.